# Тип цикла какой подразумевается?

Tags: значения

Какой вид цикла имеется в виду, если человек зацикливается на чем-л.?

While или for?

Или это образное сравнение с менструацией?

Comment: Подразумевается loop.

Comment: Вообще, тут, конечно же, подразумевается бесконечный цикл. `while(true)`, `for(;;)` и т.п. Сюда также можно отнести безусловные переходы на предшествующий код `jmp $-6`, `goto start;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подразумевается **замкнутый** (повторяющийся) цикл (repeated cycle of thinking). It's about **becoming obsessed** with something. Человек переживает или пытается до конца осмыслить навязчивую тему, но всякий раз возвращается к началу своих переживаний, и всё повторяется.